# makeAdmin google API Gsuite SDK errors

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I'm following this article to make a user an Admin for gsuite:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/makeAdmin

I'm using python to do so and my code is:

```
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'SA.json'

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

        self.delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('my_admin_user@domain.com')

        self.service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=self.delegated_credentials)
        self.service.users().makeAdmin(userKey="user.email@domain.com").execute()
```

But unfortunately I get this error:

```
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/user.email@domain.com/makeAdmin?
> returned "Missing required field: is_admin">
```

If I try to list users with:

```
users = self.service.users().list(customer='my_customer').execute()
```

it just works fine.

What is the parameter `is_admin` that the error is referring to? I can't see anything about it in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Makeadmin](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/makeAdmin) method has a body paramater as welll which takes a boolean

```
{
  "status": boolean
}
```

I think this is your missing is_admin field.

```
self.service.users().makeAdmin(userKey="user.email@domain.com", { "status": True }).execute()
```

Comment: indeed I just had to add body = {  "status": True }.